Multiple class instances sharing the same values
I'm only seeing one car when I run this code
Here's the main code:
Car leafy;
Car honda;

void setup(){
    size(1920, 1080);
    leafy=new Car(0,900);
    honda=new Car(400, 500);
}

void draw(){
    background(#736FEA);
    leafy.display();

    honda.display();
    leafy.movement();
    honda.movement();
}

here's the Car object code:
int xloc;
int yloc;

boolean windshieldControl;

class Car {
    Car(int x, int y){
        windshieldControl=true;
        xloc=x;
        yloc=y;
    }

    void display() {
        fill(#FFA600);
        rect(xloc, yloc, 150, 100);
        fill(#0B0B0D);
        circle(xloc+35, yloc+100, 30);
        circle(xloc+125, yloc+100, 30);
        fill(#7AF7F0);
        windshield();
    }

    void movement() {
        if (keyPressed) {
    
            if (key=='d' || key=='D') {
                windshieldControl=true;
                xloc=xloc+5;
            }

            if (key=='a' || key=='A') {
                xloc=xloc-5;
                windshieldControl=false;
            }
        }
    }

    void windshield() {
        if (windshieldControl) {
            arc(xloc+150, yloc+30, 100, 50, PI/2, 3*PI/2);
        }
        else {
            arc(xloc, yloc+30, 100, 50, 3*PI/2, 5*PI/2);
        }
    }
}

When I run it, I only see one car drawn - only the second one appears. Anybody know what is happening?
Thanks for your help.
I expected to see two different cars in different locations, but I only see the one car. Not sure why...,

Maybe declare xloc and yloc inside Car so they are individual?

You have successfully created two instances of Car. You only see one car, because they share the same x and y coordinate and thus get drawn overlappingly. When you are creating a car, currently you are just re-assigning the global xloc and yloc variables.
So when you create the first car, you assign xloc and yloc the values 0, 900 - and when you create the second, you reassign those same values to 400, 500
Your int xloc and int yloc are defined outside the class, hence they don't truly belong to the class as you expect them to.
If you look at the class documentation for p5, you can see you would want to use this.<varname> inside the constructor to define properties that belong to that specific instance of your class.
class Frog { 

   constructor(x, y, size) 
   { 
      // This code runs once when an instance is created. 
      this.x = x; 
      this.y = y; 
      this.size = size; 
   }
}

This way, each instance of frag has seperate x and y values, right now you are just using a variables that live outside of the class in both your class instances.

Your xloc and yloc are declared outside of the Car class, so when you call your constructor of Car and declare xloc = x yloc = y you're just changing the global values instead of the values unique to each instance of Car.
Try moving the values to the inside of Car but outside of any methods so they can remain global to the class.
class Car {
    int carX;
    int carY;

    public Car (int x, int y){
        carX = x;
        CarY = y;
    } 

// Rest of your code Here

}

